# log4net not appending to azure blob

Tags: c#, azure, log4net, azure-blob-storage

I want to append logs to azure blob storage. So i added nuget package called log4net.appender.azure.

Wrote following in app.config

```
<log4net>

<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="AzureBlobAppender" />

</root>

<appender name="AzureBlobAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AzureBlobAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
  <param name="ContainerName" value="myConatiner"/>
  <param name="DirectoryName" value="myFolder/logs.txt"/>

  <param name="ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXXX;AccountKey=Ngqa/KvLxL4zpxdPDv8Opm29JCOXTJuJsF8FrzFQZpWCOcoFm1EI+mvFu+7AJvaWEU3jDffYrf4rGOKPJu/ObA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" />
  <param name="AsText" value="true" />
</appender>
```

this is how i defined connection string

```
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
```

then i wrote below in class file

```
 log4net.ILog log =
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    log.Info("I am being tested");
```

but when i run program i dont see anything logged in azure blob. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your configuration is wrong.  According to the examples in the [README](https://github.com/Geta/log4net.Azure/blob/master/README.md)...

> ```
> <appender name="AzureBlobAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AzureBlobAppender, log4net.Appender.Azure">
>   <param name="ContainerName" value="testloggingblob"/>
>   <param name="DirectoryName" value="logs"/>
>   <!-- You can either specify a connection string or use the ConnectionStringName property instead -->
>   <param name="ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"/>
>   <!--<param name="ConnectionStringName" value="GlobalConfigurationString" />-->
>   <param name="AsText" value="true" />
> </appender>
> ```

- `myContainer` should be `ContainerName`
- `MyFolder` should be `DirectoryName`
- `AzureBlobConnectionString` should be `ConnectionStringName`

Comment: i updated my question already. can you tell if something is wrong. I dont know where i am using dll of log4net.appender.azure in code..

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps and proceed to next only if previous one is fine.
You need to check if the Logger property in debugger mode and examine the `ConfigurationMessages` property to see if any errors are reported.

First try adding a file appender to see if log4net is working fine or not.

```
<appender name="fileAppender"  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

With this, you can go to Kudo in Azure portal's webapp and see the physical file being written atleast.

Second, see if you are initializing the config properly with

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Third, check if the region of the storage account is the same as the web app or not.